# Orbot Apps VPN Mode

Tags: orbot, android

I been using Orbot since today morning and it was working just fine. But, since I recieved an update today afternoon it won't work. Orbot doesn't connect to the VPN at all.

I **activated** this feature and it didn't worked. I also tried the **cancel** button and it would just not work. Any idea how might I fix it?

Should I need to post the side logs which we get in the app?

[image]

Comment: Have you also configured the specific app(s) to use Orbot's "Apps VPN Mode"? If so, check that Orbot is actually working, IE use Orfox to see if you can hit a `.onion` address, look at the logs, etc.